# Group data frame by elements from a variable containing lists of elements

Tags: r, group-by, tidyverse

I would like to perform a a non-trivial `group_by`, grouping and summarizing a data frame by **single elements** of lists found in one of its variables.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5)
df$y <- list("A", c("A", "B"), "C", c("B", "D", "C"), "E")
df
 x       y
1 1       A
2 2    A, B
3 3       C
4 4 B, D, C
5 5       E
```

Now grouping by `y` (and say counting no. of rows), which is a variable holding lists of elements, the required end results should be:

```
data.frame(group = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), n = c(2,2,2,1,1))
  group n
1     A 2
2     B 2
3     C 2
4     D 1
5     E 1
```

Because "A" appears in 2 rows, "B" in 2 rows, etc.

Note: the sum of `n` is not necessarily equal to number of rows in the data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use **simple base R** solution with `table` to calculate the frequency after `unlist`ing the `list` and then create a `data.table` based on that table object

```
tbl <- table(unlist(df$y))
data.frame(group = names(tbl), n = as.vector(tbl))
#  group n
#1     A 2
#2     B 2
#3     C 2
#4     D 1
#5     E 1
```

---

Or another option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
unnest(df) %>% 
     group_by(group = y) %>% 
     summarise(n=n())
#     <chr> <int>
#1     A     2
#2     B     2
#3     C     2
#4     D     1
#5     E     1
```

---

Or as @alexis_laz mentioned in the comments, an alternative is `as.data.frame.table`

```
as.data.frame(table(group = unlist(df$y)), responseName = "n")
```

Comment: A convenient alternative is `as.data.frame.table` -- `as.data.frame(table(group = unlist(df$y)), responseName = "n")`

Comment: I like the `tidyverse` solution better as the summary function isn't necessarily count no. of rows, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

simple base R solution: (actually this is dup question, unable to locate it though)

```
sapply(unique(unlist(df$y)), function(x) sum(grepl(x, df$y))
# A B C D E 
# 2 2 2 1 1
```